# How to filter reply history in email

Tags: regex

I am trying to retrieve only the new part of an email, without the trailing conversation history

For example, I want the following

```
looks like it yes
> On 19 Feb 2016, at 22:05,  wrote:
> 
> this is an old reply
> 
> If you'd like to unsubscribe and stop receiving these emails click here
```

to only retrieve

```
looks like it yes
```

I was thinking of using a like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 \n]*>
```

To end at the first `>` but this is obviously not very robust, and I am having a difficult time coming up with a solid regex

Comment: Maybe just [`^[^>\n].*`](https://regex101.com/r/kT1xE4/3)? Or [`^(?!>).*`](https://regex101.com/r/kT1xE4/2)?

Comment: If the email has any > on it, the solution fails. It's a good idea to think of a new regular expression.

Comment: Exactly, Im not even sure if the > is a universal standard?

Comment: What language are you using on that?

Comment: By the way: I was thinking about the pattern for old messages. I suppose there are at least two > and a \n in the middle of them, is that right for all examples? That, which you want to discard, could be matched like this: (<.*\n)+<.*

Comment: I see, the problem is that Im not sure if all messages are formatted that way

Comment: You could try to understand the pattern of the messages. Through that, you have your answer. For instance, let x be the RE that matches the old messages. You could do a global substitution from x to "" (empty string).

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
[>][A-Za-z 0-9,:'\n]*
```

remove all characters begin from >

Comment: doesn't take special character nto account

Comment: what's special characters, I can't sea any, other